# Splitting a string of a multiline textbox by lines

Tags: excel, vba, text, split, textbox

I want to split the text of a textbox after a specific amount of visible lines.

I've found some codes that "allows that", but all of them consider the lines by the "vbCrLf" parameter, but i want to split using the visible lines of a multiline textbox.

To make it more clear to understand, consider a multiline textbox with the following text:

"The history of textbooks dates back to civilizations of ancient history. For example, Ancient Greeks wrote texts intended for education. The modern textbook has its roots in the standardization made possible by the printing press. Johannes Gutenberg himself may have printed editions of Ars Minor, a schoolbook on Latin grammar by Aelius Donatus. Early textbooks were used by tutors and teachers, who used the books as instructional aids (e.g., alphabet books), as well as individuals who taught themselves."

When i use the `Textbox.Linecount` function it returns the number 6 because the textbox shows six lines (which depends on the size of the control), but if i use a function like `strText = Split(TextBox.Text, vbCrLf)` it will return 1, because there is only one `vbCrLf`. But i need to split the text into two textbox considering the visible lines of the control, something like what happens in page breaks of MS Word.

For a better visual explanation, please look at the attached image.

Example
[image: Example]

Comment: Why not split in the middle of the string (making the necessary adjustment to avoid splitting up a word) ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not convinced there is a robust and elegant way to do this, but it was fun to experiment and it might be useful to you.

The following will split the contents of `TextBoxInput` into `TextBoxPage1` and `TextBoxPage2` breaking on the line number specified by `PAGED_TEXT_BOX_LINES`.

It uses the textbox itself to detect natural line breaks and thus implicitly caters for the size of the textbox, the font, etc.

The desired line count is hard coded as a constant - not doing this would require an alternative of calculating the line height of the textbox (requiring calculations based on the font metrics and the textbox's internal line-leading size).

It only handles two "pages". But the concept could be extended simply by repeating the process based on the remainder of text that ends up in `TextBoxPage2`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const PAGED_TEXT_BOX_LINES As Integer = 5
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim textLength As Long
    Dim curLine As Integer
    text = TextBoxInput.text
    textLength = Len(text)
    TextBoxPage1.SetFocus
    'add characters of the input string until the first page textbox
    ' exceeds maximum line count
    For i = 1 To textLength
        TextBoxPage1.text = Mid$(text, 1, i)
        If TextBoxPage1.LineCount > PAGED_TEXT_BOX_LINES Then
            'retreat cursor until we reach previous line, so we can
            ' detect the word that wrapped
            curLine = TextBoxPage1.curLine
            Do While TextBoxPage1.curLine = curLine
                TextBoxPage1.SelStart = TextBoxPage1.SelStart - 1
            Loop
            'the remaining text after the SelStart is what
            ' wrapped, so stop page 1 after SelStart
            TextBoxPage1.text = Mid$(text, 1, TextBoxPage1.SelStart)
            TextBoxPage2.text = Trim$(Mid$(text, TextBoxPage1.SelStart + 1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my god, that's exactly what I wanted. You're a genius! Thank you very much!